# Certain background images not appearing in sections on mobile devices?

Tags: html, image, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, background

The first few background images appear on mobile devices but the last couple don't show up?

heres a link to it live: http://ryan-playground.com/cafe_neve_v2/

It works fine on a desktop but on my iphone and my friends galaxy the last two background images do not appear. All of the background images have the same css styling so it doesn't make sense for them not to appear?

heres the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Café Névé</title>
        <meta name="generator" content="Bootply" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/creative.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel='shortcut icon' href='img/favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'/ >
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-offset="50">

<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top"><!--Café Névé--></a>
                <div>
    <a href='https://www.facebook.com/Caf%C3%A9-N%C3%A9v%C3%A9-86198556375/' target='blank'><img class='facebooklink' src='img/blue_facebook.png'></a>
            <a  href='https://instagram.com/explore/locations/410052/' target='blank'><img class='instagramlink' src='img/blue_instagram.png'></a>
          </div>
            </div>


            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#sec1">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#sec3">Rachel</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#sec4">Mile End</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#sec5">Stanley</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="page-scroll" href="#sec6">Toronto</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

<div class="header alt vert">
  <div class="container">

    <h1 id='topheader'> Café Névé

      <p class="lead"><img src='img/snowflake.png'></p></h1>
  </div>


<div id="sec1" class="blurb">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h1 id='who'>Who We Are</h1>
        <p class="lead"><!--The Most Popular Responsive Framework--></p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="featurette" id="sec2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
       <!-- <h1>Amazing Features</h1> -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
        <div class="featurette-item">
          <i class="icon-rocket"></i>
          <h4>Mission</h4>
          <p>Words we live by</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
        <div class="featurette-item">
          <i class="icon-magnet"></i>
          <h4>History</h4>
          <p>Where we came from</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
        <div class="featurette-item">
          <i class="icon-shield"></i>
          <h4>Source</h4>
          <p>What we brew and why</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 text-center">
        <div class="featurette-item">
          <i class="icon-pencil"></i>
          <h4>Retailers</h4>
          <p>Where you can get our coffee</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="callout" id="sec3">
  <div class="vert">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h2>RACHEL LOCATION</h2></div>
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="callout" id="sec4">
  <div class="vert">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h2>MILE END LOCATION</h2></div>
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="callout" id="sec5">
  <div class="vert">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h2>STANLEY LOCATION</h2></div>
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="callout" id="sec6">
  <div class="vert">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h2>TORONTO LOCATION</h2></div>
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="blurb bright">

  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
        <h3>Founding Partners</h3>
        <br>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-2">
         <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading text-center"><h2> Luke</h2></div>
         <div class="panel-body text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
          Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis 
          dolor, in sagittis nisi. Sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. 
          Aliquam in felis si.

          </div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="panel panel-default">
         <div class="panel-heading text-center"><h2>Gabriel </h2></div>
         <div class="panel-body text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis pharetra varius quam sit amet vulputate. 
          Quisque mauris augue, molestie tincidunt condimentum vitae, gravida a libero. Aenean sit amet felis 
          dolor, in sagittis nisi. Sed ac orci quis tortor imperdiet venenatis. Duis elementum auctor accumsan. 
          Aliquam in felis sit.



          </div>
         </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--
<div class="blurb">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
        <h3>Sharing the Bootstrap Love</h3>
        <p class="lead"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
        <ul class="list-inline">
          <li><i class="icon-facebook icon-2x"></i></li>
          <li><i class="icon-twitter icon-2x"></i></li>
          <li><i class="icon-google-plus icon-2x"></i></li>
          <li><i class="icon-pinterest icon-2x"></i></li>
        </ul>
        <hr>
        <p>Built with <i class="icon-heart-empty"></i> at <a href="http://www.bootply.com">Bootply</a>.<br>Company ©2014</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>

<ul class="nav pull-right scroll-down">
  <li><a href="#" title="Scroll down"><i class="icon-chevron-down icon-3x"></i></a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav pull-right scroll-top">
  <li><a href="#" title="Scroll to top"><i class="icon-chevron-up icon-3x"></i></a></li>
</ul>-->

    <!-- script references -->
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And heres the css:

```
/* -- custom css for Bootstrap 3.x --*/

/* move special fonts to HTML head for better performance */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Voltaire);

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
}

/* fix bs3 horizontal scrollbar bug */
.row { margin: 0; padding: 0 }


/* use special fonts in certain elements */
h1,h2,h3,h4,.lead,.btn,.navbar a {
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-family:'Voltaire',Arial,sans-serif;
  letter-spacing:2px;
}

h1 {
  font-size:50px;
}

/* make images gray */
img.grayscale {
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
    filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
}

.facebooklink{

 width:18px;
  height:auto;
  margin-top: 14px;
  position: absolute;
    margin-left: 15px;


}


.instagramlink{

 width:18px;
  height:auto;
  margin-top: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -10px;

}

.icon-bar {
   background-color:#fff;
}

.scroll-down a, .scroll-top a {
   color:#ffffff;
}

.scroll-down {
   position:fixed;
   bottom:20%;
   right:0%;
   color:#f9f9f9;
}

.scroll-top {
  background-color:#dbdbdb;
}

#sec1{}
#sec2{}
#sec3{

background: url('../img/1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 

}

#sec4{

background: url('../img/3.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 

}


#sec5{

background: url('../img/4.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 

}

#sec6{

background: url('../img/6.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 

}

.vert {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width:100%;
  padding-top:4%;
  text-align:center;
}

.header .btn-lg {
   font-size:28px;
   border-color:#eeeeee;
   padding:15px;
   background-color:transparent;
   color:#ffffff;
}

.header .btn-lg:hover {
   background-color:#eeeeee;
   color:#777777;
}

.navbar a {
  color:#87d6fd;
  font-size:14px;
}

.navbar-bold.affix {
  background-color:#d46054;
}

.affix {
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
  }

  .affix + .container-fluid {
      padding-top: 70px;
  }

.navbar-bold {
  background-color:#f68076;
  font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}

.navbar-bold li a:hover, .navbar-bold li.active {
  background-color:#d46054;
}


.header h1 {
  font-size:60px;
  margin-top: 120px;
  color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
  margin-left:-5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}



.header .lead {
  color:#d46054;
  font-size:25px;
}

.header {
  height: 100%;
  background: #f68076 url('../img/2_blur.jpg') repeat center center fixed;
}

#navbar{


}

/* use alt in navbar and header for different color */

.alt {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

.alt .lead {
  color: #3B0496;
}

.alt.affix {
  background-color:#4C06AB;
}

.alt li a:hover, .alt li.active {
  background-color:#5D17BA;
}

#topheader{



}



.blurb {

  padding: 120px 0;


}

.blurb .panel {

  background-color:transparent;
}

.bright {
  height: 100%;
  background:white; 
  color:#777;
}

#who{

margin-top: 200px;



}

.featurette {

  background: #fff;
  padding: 50px 0;
  color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.7);
}

.featurette-item {

  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.featurette-item > i {
  border: 3px solid #87d6fd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 56px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  line-height: 136px;
  vertical-align: middle; 
  text-align: center;
}

.featurette-item > i:hover {
  font-size: 68px;
}

.callout {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding-top:7%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.gallery {
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.call-to-action {
  background: #eeeeee;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.call-to-action .btn {
  margin: 10px;
}

footer {
  padding: 100px 0;
}

/* -- end custom css for Bootstrap 3.x --*/
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]http://ami.responsivedesign.is/
Hi friend,
your website its working all devices(all images are display both mobile and desktop)...please check your website above link...

Comment: It seems to work on your responsive design tester but it doesn't work on an actual iPhone which it needs to.